# Pass textarea value to javascript with button onclick

Tags: javascript, php, textarea

I have a below PHP code to pass TextArea value to call another PHP page using button onclick. When I type some chars in the text area and click on the button, it does not take value to the mspec parameter.

```
echo "<TEXTAREA name=Tranrules cols=100 rows=5></TEXTAREA>"

echo "<INPUT TYPE=BUTTON VALUE=\"Add Mapping\"
 onClick=\"javascript:JSopenReportWindow('sample8.php?mspec=$Tranrules');\" style=\"color:black; width:153px;\">";
```

Javascript is below

```
<script language="JavaScript">

    function JSopenReportWindow(URL) {
        popupWin = window.open(URL, 'Report',
        'toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=1,resizable=1,width=675,height=600');
        popupWin.focus(); // bring window to front
    }
</script>
```

Comment: because `$Tranrules` doesn't exist. You should call you function with the name of the textarea and in your function get the text within that textarea

Answer (score 1):

here is a little sample of what you should be doing instead:

```
<script>
function popup(name){
    var text = document.getElementsByName(name)[0].value;
    alert(text);
}
</script>

<textarea name="Transrule"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="submit" onClick="javascript:popup('Transrule');" />
```

Comment: Thanks. However, my requirement is to pass the TextArea value as a java script parameter but NOT as output of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

When You echo the HTML, it is HTML, so You cant access element's value by adding $ to name, You should use ID instead of Name and access it the right way.

http://jsfiddle.net/bE84a/

```
echo "<TEXTAREA id=Tranrules cols=100 rows=5></TEXTAREA>"

echo "<INPUT TYPE=BUTTON VALUE=\"Add Mapping\"
 onClick=\"javascript:JSopenReportWindow('sample8.php?mspec='+document.getElementById('Tranrules').value);\"
                style=\"color:black; width:153px;\">";
```

Comment: Thanks, Skriptotajs. This helps!